# How would I select a random word from a file for a user to unscramble?

Tags: python

I am trying to select a random word from a txt file. The context of the file has been provided. I would like the word to be random every time the code is ran. I also only need the words before the comma

```
import random 
print("Please enter mywords file to start game")

user_input=input('Enter file name')
filename = open(user_input)
info=filename.readlines()
filename.close()

words=info[0-3]
objects=words.split(',')
userword=random.choice(objects)
print(userword)
```

```
opulence,great wealth
penury,extremely poor
gregarious,fond of company; sociable
entomology,study of insects
```

So far I  able to pull from the second line in the file 
"penury,extremely poor"

Comment: *"So far I able to pull from the second line in the file.."* I don't think with `words=info[0-3]` you were able to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Please [edit] the code to make it a [mre]. For example, you know how to read a file and get `info`, so that's not relevant. Just provide the value of `info`.

Comment: @Austin I'm not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to slice, but end up with just one line. You can do a loop over the lines, split on `','` and form a list with what's required. Later, randomly pick from the list:

```
lst = []

for x in info:
    w, _ = x.split(',')
    lst.append(w)

print(random.choice(lst))
```

Comment: Hey man thank you! Would you mind explaining this to me? The code runs but I would like to know the details so that I can understand it

Comment: Please find the details on the top of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`0-3` seems to be a typo of `0:3`, but the problem goes deeper than that. `words` is supposed to be a list, and lists don't have a `.split` method. You'll need to split each item (and select the part before the comma).

```
words = [line.split(',')[0] for line in info]
userword = random.choice(words)
```

Comment: Got it. Could you explain the [0] please?

Comment: @Xavier `str.split` returns a list, and `[0]` just selects the first element of that list.